# Kirchhoff's Voltage Law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given:

Kirchhoff’s voltage law states that the sum of the voltage drops across an inductor, L dI/dt, and across a resistor, IR, must be the same as the voltage source, E(t), applied to the circuit. The resulting ODE model is LdI/dt+IR=E(t). If a 12-volt battery is connected to an RL circuit with a ½ henry inductor, L,  and a 10 ohm resistor, R , find the current I(t) given that I(0)=0.

Ok, so I understand the formula is $E(t)=L(dI/dt)+IR$, but what is confusing me is with the mention of I(t).  How do I begin to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: All I know is what you see there, unfortunately.  I feel that this problem wasn't explained very clearly...

Comment: If $E(t)$ is the voltage source, and the voltage source is a $12$-volt battery, then it seems like $E(t)=12$. Right?

Comment: I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Can you take it from there?

Comment: I'm looking at it now.  What confuses me is the I(0).  Does this look right?:

12=1/2(dI/dt)+0

Comment: Not quite. $I$ might start at $0$, but because you're adding current from the battery, it's going to get larger. See Amzoti's answer.

Comment: When you solve the equation, you will be left with an unknown constant, and you will use the information $I(0)=0$ to find that constant.

Comment: Context is good, but this isn't ECE-SE, so the lead is somewhat buried. The essentials are: you have a differential equation $Lf^\prime +Rf-E=0$ with boundary condition $f(0)=0$. I propose editing the question to reflect that (even though a complete answer already exists).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: this is a separable equation:

$$L(dI/dt) = E - IR$$

So, we can separate and integrate:

$$\int \dfrac{L}{E-IR}~dI = \int dt$$